# ¿Cuál es el significado de un cursor vacío en agregación?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mongodb, agregación

Estoy viendo algo de agregaciones en **[mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb)** con `pymongo 3.2.2`. La pregunta es: ¿por qué ellos en la documentación utilizan un `cursor` vacío en un ejemplo de agregaciones, algo como esto:

```
>>> for result in collection.aggregate([], cursor={}):
...     pass
```

El `cursor={}`, está vacío y no entiendo porqué lo hacen. Dicen que se usa para un comportamiento consistente, pero en realidad no me queda muy claro. Luego busqué en la `api de mongo` y encontré un uso para el cursor:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
                     [
                       { $match: { status: "A" } },
                       { $group: { _id: "$cust_id", total: { $sum: "$amount" } } },
                       { $sort: { total: -1 } },
                       { $limit: 2 }
                     ],
                     {
                       cursor: { batchSize: 0 }
                     }
                   )
```

El uso del `cursor` en este caso si lo entiendo y sé para qué sirve. Pero el uso para el caso anterior no sé qué significa. Alguien que se haya topado con esta pregunta o sepa la definición, le agredecería que me ayude.

Answer (score 0):

No he sido capaz de encontrar la referencia de ese `cursor` vacío. Tiene toda la pinta de tratarse de algún resto de la documentación javascript que se quedó en la documentación de pymongo.

En pymongo siempre se usa un cursor por defecto (opción `useCursor=True`). Si quieres modificar el `batchSize`, basta añadir la opción como *argumento nominal*, `batchSize=0` ([documentación de `aggregate`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate)).

Si crees que no es un error de la documentación, añade la referencia concreta que estás mirando para poder indicarte mejor.

Comment: Si en pymongo siempre se usa el cursor por defecto, pero mi pregunta es respecto a la agregación, porque está vacio, mira el link de la documentación  https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html?highlight=aggregation, la parte de agregación.

Comment: Ya he encontrado la referencia y voy a darte una nueva respuesta. Te recomiendo que la referencia la añadas a la pregunta inicial.

Answer (score 0):

Con la [referencia](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html?highlight=aggregation) que has añadido, entiendo mejor el problema.

A partir de la versión 2.6, mongodb introdujo los cursores, que se crean añadiendo el atributo `cursor:{}` a los parámetros de `aggregate`. El equivalente en pymongo era pasar el argumento `cursor={}`, un diccionario vacío, que de ninguna manera hay que ver como un *"cursor vacío"*.

Cuando se usan cursores, `aggregate` retorna un iterador de la clase `CommandControl`. En general, en python, los iteradores son mucho más apropiados que las listas o diccionario para procesar largas secuencias de resultados. A partir de la versión 2.9, el uso de cursores se convirtió en el comportamiento por defecto y ya no hacía falta pasar el argumento `cursor={}`, pasando los parámetros de control del cursor directamente como argumentos nominales de `aggregate`.

La documentación que estás leyendo son recomendaciones para facilitar la migración. Como en la versión 3 siempre se usan cursores, recomienda modificar los programas antiguos para que usen también cursores. El argumento `cursor={}` sólo sirve para crear estos cursores en las versiones viejas; a partir de la versión 2.9 no se emplea y se ignora. Cuando se habla de *"coherencia"* se refiere a que todas las versiones usen cursores.